Pandoc Lua filter to output only image captions with specific paragraph style
I prepare documents in Markdown to convert via Pandoc to HTML and ICML (InDesign).
Exporting Images to InDesign proved to be unpractical.
The goal was to write a lua-filter which only returns the caption of the image while preserving the ParagraphStyleRange "Caption". The image source itself should not be exported. The effect should be, that in InDesign you will be provided with correctly styled caption (inkluding source reference) but will be able to position and size the image according to the optimal "text-flow".
Given a Markdown file with the content
![Caption [(Image: Source)]{custom-style="ImageSource"}](image.jpg)

The following lua snippet actually returns only the caption. It also preserves the CharacterStyleRange "ImageSource", but it does not export the ParagraphStyleRange "Caption".
function Image(bild)
  if FORMAT:match 'icml' then -- Only export to icml
    -- Check if caption is empty
    if #bild.caption > 0 then
      return bild.caption
    end
  end
end

This ist what ends up in the ICML-Export. It seems to me that these correspond to two paragraphs, which I do not understand ...
    <!-- body needs to be non-indented, otherwise code blocks are indented too far -->
<ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="">
  <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="$ID/NormalCharacterStyle">
    <Content>Caption </Content>
  </CharacterStyleRange>
  <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/ImageSource">
    <Content>(Image: Source)</Content>
  </CharacterStyleRange>
</ParagraphStyleRange>
<Br />
<ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="">
  <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="$ID/NormalCharacterStyle">
    <Content>Caption </Content>
  </CharacterStyleRange>
  <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/ImageSource">
    <Content>(Image: Source)</Content>
  </CharacterStyleRange>
</ParagraphStyleRange>

I tried to put just the line
function Image () return {} end

in the filter, which should just delete the Image (as I understood from How can I strip figures and table during a pandoc LaTeX to Word conversion?). But still in icml-export I get two ParagraphStyleRange the first of which is now empty. I am confused.

After much try and error I came to the conclusion, that a much simpler and above all a working solution to this problem would be the use of "sed" to find and replace image-syntax with the respective custom-styles. sed -n "s/![(.)](.)({[^}]*})?/[\1]{custom-style="Caption"}/p; t; p" %~nx1 > %~n1-captions.md is what I use and it seems to work just fine. The output then can be used to process with pandoc.
